# how to find difference between two array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3
        )

)
Array
(
    [c_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

output should be

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

Comment: Surely the difference should be `[0] => 4`?

Comment: but................. how?

Comment: array_diff($array1, $array2);

Comment: @Nick.. yes sorry ..output should be array([0]=>4)

Comment: @ACD after using array_diff()...Array to string conversion notice error genrate..